# How to flip the color of all the vertices in a graph by flipping the color of a vertex and it's adjacent vertex

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose there is a simple graph, and each vertices are colored white at the beginning. Now you can do the following operation, select a vertex, and flip the color of it and it's adjacent vertices. (White->Black, Black->White)

Now I want to show that I can always flip the color to black for all vertices.

This problem can be also viewed as the following: The 0,1 adjacent matrix $G$ (satisfy $G_{ii}=1$) of a simple graph contains $(1,...,1)$ in the range space in $F_2$. But I don't know how to prove it if $G$ is not invertable.

Either linear algebra or combinatorial proof are welcome.

Comment: I had to read your next to final paragraph more than once to see your point.  You consider the *adjacency matrix* of the graph plus the identity matrix(?) to get ones on the diagonal.  Perhaps an example would make your idea clearer for many Readers.

Comment: Yeah, your understanding is correct. I found the answer already, and it requires to use the identity Im(G) = perp(ker G^T), so directly check that the all one vector is perpendicular to the ker G suffice.

Comment: Here is a [brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to posting mathematical notation.  Note that the adjacency matrix of a simple graph is symmetric, and it would follow that $G^T = G$.